# ModifyDOM to clear text launched by a radio button

Tags: javascript

I have made a form that I can clear with a reset button. On this form, I have four radio buttons (that code is towards the top). When a button is selected, info comes up using "displayText". I want to attach an onclick handler to launch a function that deletes/closes that div when reset button is hit.
Someone suggested this but I can't get it to work.
document.getElementById("info").remove();

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Infotech 550 Form</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Popper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  #form {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }
  .infoText {
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: blue
  }
  p.padding2 {
   padding-top: 1%;
   margin-left: 30px;
   color: indigo
 }
  </style>
  <script>

  function textToDisplay (radioValue){
    var displayText = "";
    if (radioValue =="1"){
      displayText = "I have no use for audio products in my library"
    } else if (radioValue == "2"){
      displayText = "Not very interested in using Audacity for anything in my library"
    } else if (radioValue == "3"){
      displayText = "Interesting program but no practical application at this time"
    } else if (radioValue == "4"){
      displayText = "I am going to learn more, I think there are ways Audacity could be useful in my library"
    } else if (radioValue == "5"){
      displayText = "I am going to use Audacity in my library for a local audio history project"
    }



    return (displayText);
  }


  // modify DOM function
  function modifyDOM (radioInput) {
    console.log(radioInput.name + " + " + radioInput.value);
    var displayText = textToDisplay(radioInput.value);
    var insertionNode = document.getElementById("radioButtons");
    var infoNode = document.getElementById("info");
    if (infoNode === null) {
      console.log("infoNode does not exist yet.");
      var node = document.createElement("DIV");
      // console.log(node);
      node.setAttribute("id", "info");
      node.className = "form-text infoText";
      var textnode = document.createTextNode(displayText);
      node.appendChild(textnode);
      insertionNode.appendChild(node);
    } else {
      console.log("infoNode DOES exist.");
      infoNode.innerHTML = displayText;
    }
    function clearResult(){
      document.getElementById("info").remove();
        
      }
}
// test how many checkboxes selected //
  function checkboxesSelected (checkboxes, errorString) {
    console.log("checkboxesSelected function");
    // keep a count of how many checkboxes have been selected ... initially zero
    // have to use var cbSelected = 0;
    // 2) Good practice to have var when declaring a variable ...not doing it in our JavaScript examples to not add more complexity.
    var cbSelected = 0;
    // for loop: first need an index i to iterate through array of checkboxes;
    // start at beginning of array of checkboxes
    // i=0 means we start at beginning of array
    // test if all elements of array have been tested... know if i < checkboxes.length that we have still elements to examine
    // i-- means that we subtract -1 from i
    for (i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
      // test if current checkbox is checked ... if yes, add 1 to counter
      if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
        // increment counter
        cbSelected += 1;
      }
    }
    // test how many checkboxes have been selected ...
    // if checkboxesSelected equal to 0, then we have not and return errorString
    if (cbSelected <= 1) {
      return (errorString);
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }
  // validate function that calls other functions and acculumates errorString and test if this is empty or not //
  function validate (form) {
    console.log("validate form");
    var fail = "";
    fail += checkboxesSelected(form.bed_extras, "At least TWO Audacity uses need to be selected.\n")
    if (fail == "") return true
    else { alert(fail); return false }
  }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
<!-- Brand -->
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">AVM Game</a>
<!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
 <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<!-- Navbar links -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">

<!-- Links -->
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle active" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Infotech 550
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="Ex4_review.html">Open Source Tool Review</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="Ex4_form.html">Feedback Form</a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Interests
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Interest 1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Interest 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Interest 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
<div>
<h1>Open-Source Project Data Collection</h1>
<h2>(Thank you for participating in our study)</h2>
</div>
    <form id="form" method="post" action="mailto:stephentruddy@yahoo.com" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
      <fieldset id="personal" class="form-group">
        <legend>Personal Data</legend>
        <div class="form-inline">
          <label for="firstname" class="mr-sm-2">First Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter First Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline">
          <label for="lastname" class="mr-sm-2">Last Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline">
          <label for="email" class="mr-sm-2">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter A Valid Email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline">
          <label for="state" class="mr-sm-2">State:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="state" name="state" placeholder="Enter Two Letter State " pattern="[A-Z]{2}" title="State needs to be TWO CAPITAL letters"]required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline">
          <label for="firstname" class="mr-sm-2">Zipcode:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="zipcode" name="zipcode" placeholder="Enter 5 Digit Zipcode " pattern="[0-9]{5}" title="Zipcode needs to be 5 numbers"] required >
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Questions About Audacity</legend>
        <label>Rate your interest in using Audacicity in your library (1 being lowest):</label>
        <div id="radioButtons" class="form-group">
          <div class="form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
              <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="bed_size" value="1" required onclick="modifyDOM(this)">
              1</label>
            </div>
              <div class="form-check-inline">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="bed_size" value="2" required onclick="modifyDOM(this)">
                  2</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check-inline">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="bed_size" value="3" required onclick="modifyDOM(this)">
                  3</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check-inline">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="bed_size" value="4" required onclick="modifyDOM(this)">
                  4</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check-inline">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="bed_size" value="5" required onclick="modifyDOM(this)">
                  5</label>
              </div>
          </div>
          <label>How would use Audacity (check at least TWO options)</label>
          <div id="checkboxes" class="form-group">
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="bed_extras" value="oralhistory">
                Oral History
              </label>
            </div>

              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="bed_extras" value="multimedia">
                  Multimedia
                </label>
              </div>

                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                  <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="bed_extras" value="dailynews">
                    Daily News
                  </label>
                </div>

                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="bed_extras" value="podcast">
                      Podcasts
                    </label>
                  </div>

                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="bed_extras" value="natual world">
                        The Natural World
                      </label>
                    </div>
          </div>

      </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset" onclick="clearResult(this)">
  </form>
  <footer><p class="padding2">c. New World InfoTechnologies Corporation</p></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the future, please pare down your code to be a minimal, reproducible example.  There is far too much code represented here for the problem you are trying to solve.  Makes it difficult for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You had your `clearResult` function inside the scope of your `modifyDOM` function.  Move it to the global scope to call it directly from your html `onclick` handler.

```js
function textToDisplay(radioValue) {
  var displayText = "";
  if (radioValue == "1") {
    displayText = "I have no use for audio products in my library"
  } else if (radioValue == "2") {
    displayText = "Not very interested in using Audacity for anything in my library"
  } else if (radioValue == "3") {
    displayText = "Interesting program but no practical application at this time"
  } else if (radioValue == "4") {
    displayText = "I am going to learn more, I think there are ways Audacity could be useful in my library"
  } else if (radioValue == "5") {
    displayText = "I am going to use Audacity in my library for a local audio history project"
  }



  return (displayText);
}


// modify DOM function
function modifyDOM(radioInput) {
  console.log(radioInput.name + " + " + radioInput.value);
  var displayText = textToDisplay(radioInput.value);
  var insertionNode = document.getElementById("radioButtons");
  var infoNode = document.getElementById("info");
  if (infoNode === null) {
    console.log("infoNode does not exist yet.");
    var node = document.createElement("div");
    // console.log(node);
    node.setAttribute("id", "info");
    node.className = "form-text infoText";
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(displayText);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    insertionNode.appendChild(node);
  } else {
    console.log("infoNode DOES exist.");
    infoNode.innerHTML = displayText;
  }
}

function clearResult() {
  var info = document.getElementById("info");
  var infoParent = document.getElementById("radioButtons")
  infoParent.removeChild(info)

}
// test how many checkboxes selected //
function checkboxesSelected(checkboxes, errorString) {
  console.log("checkboxesSelected function");
  // keep a count of how many checkboxes have been selected ... initially zero
  // have to use var cbSelected = 0;
  // 2) Good practice to have var when declaring a variable ...not doing it in our JavaScript examples to not add more complexity.
  var cbSelected = 0;
  // for loop: first need an index i to iterate through array of checkboxes;
  // start at beginning of array of checkboxes
  // i=0 means we start at beginning of array
  // test if all elements of array have been tested... know if i < checkboxes.length that we have still elements to examine
  // i-- means that we subtract -1 from i
  for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    // test if current checkbox is checked ... if yes, add 1 to counter
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
      // increment counter
      cbSelected += 1;
    }
  }
  // test how many checkboxes have been selected ...
  // if checkboxesSelected equal to 0, then we have not and return errorString
  if (cbSelected <= 1) {
    return (errorString);
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}
// validate function that calls other functions and acculumates errorString and test if this is empty or not //
function validate(form) {
  console.log("validate form");
  var fail = "";
  fail += checkboxesSelected(form.bed_extras, "At least TWO Audacity uses need to be selected.\n")
  if (fail == "") return true
  else {
    alert(fail);
    return false
  }
}
```

```css
#form {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.infoText {
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: blue
}

p.padding2 {
  padding-top: 1%;
  margin-left: 30px;
  color: indigo
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Infotech 550 Form</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Popper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
      <!-- Brand -->
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">AVM Game</a>
      <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
 <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

      <!-- Navbar links -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">

        <!-- Links -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle active" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Infotech 550
    </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="Ex4_review.html">Open Source Tool Review</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="Ex4_form.html">Feedback Form</a>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Interests
    </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Interest 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Interest 2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Interest 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div>
      <h1>Open-Source Project Data Collection</h1>
      <h2>(Thank you for participating in our study)</h2>
    </div>
    <form id="form" method="post" action="mailto:stephentruddy@yahoo.com" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
      <fieldset id="personal" class="form-group">
        <legend>Personal Data</legend>
        <div class="form-inline">
          <label for="firstname" class="mr-sm-2">First Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter First Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline">
          <label for="lastname" class="mr-sm-2">Last Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline">
          <label for="email" class="mr-sm-2">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter A Valid Email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline">
          <label for="state" class="mr-sm-2">State:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="state" name="state" placeholder="Enter Two Letter State " pattern="[A-Z]{2}" title="State needs to be TWO CAPITAL letters" ]required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline">
          <label for="firstname" class="mr-sm-2">Zipcode:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="zipcode" name="zipcode" placeholder="Enter 5 Digit Zipcode " pattern="[0-9]{5}" title="Zipcode needs to be 5 numbers" ] required>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Questions About Audacity</legend>
        <label>Rate your interest in using Audacicity in your library (1 being lowest):</label>
        <div id="radioButtons" class="form-group">
          <div class="form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
              <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="bed_size" value="1" required onclick="modifyDOM(this)">
              1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="bed_size" value="2" required onclick="modifyDOM(this)">
                  2</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="bed_size" value="3" required onclick="modifyDOM(this)">
                  3</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="bed_size" value="4" required onclick="modifyDOM(this)">
                  4</label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                  <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="bed_size" value="5" required onclick="modifyDOM(this)">
                  5</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <label>How would use Audacity (check at least TWO options)</label>
        <div id="checkboxes" class="form-group">
          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="bed_extras" value="oralhistory">
                Oral History
              </label>
          </div>

          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="bed_extras" value="multimedia">
                  Multimedia
                </label>
          </div>

          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="bed_extras" value="dailynews">
                    Daily News
                  </label>
          </div>

          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="bed_extras" value="podcast">
                      Podcasts
                    </label>
          </div>

          <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="bed_extras" value="natual world">
                        The Natural World
                      </label>
          </div>
        </div>

      </fieldset>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
      <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset" onclick="clearResult(this)">
    </form>
    <footer>
      <p class="padding2">c. New World InfoTechnologies Corporation</p>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```